# WindowsPE - How to run electron app, missing dll

Tags: windows, dll, electron, portable-executable

Hello Computer enthusiasts,

i try to run my electron app on windows pe.
When i try to start the app trough the "startnet.cmd" nothing happens.

If i want to start it over "procex64.exe" (Windows Process Explorer, from Sysinternals) i get the error that some ddl's are missing

- msdmo.dll
- dxgi.dll
- d3d9.dll (DirectX ?)
- dxva2.dll

Anyone know what this is, how i can fix that problem ?

[image]

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

copy they files from a full windows installation to your windows pe image,
c:\windows\system32:

- BCP47Langs.dll
- d3d9.dll
- d3d11.dll
- dxgi.dll
- dxva2.dll
- msdmo.dll

(Tested/Found on Windows 10 Pro)

Is just a simple electron app with a single page and a few buttons. Perhaps there are other *.dll's if you work with media files or similar.